# Locking cells based on criteria in other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which will be used to manage documents and information required for various projects. I would like some of these cells to be colored and locked depending on the information entered in another cell.

Before I go into detail, I should mention that I am completely new to macros and VBA so my knowledge is extremely basic. These columns are subject to change so in addition to a code, I would like to know how I can edit the code to include additional columns or how to remove them. In addition, I will have over 500 rows of data that this will need to apply to, and the final product will be protected.

I have added a link to a document that is similar to the one I am actually working on (due to my company’s security restrictions, I cannot upload the original). He are the conditions I currently need to meet:

- If `“Single Source”` is selected in column `B`, columns `E-H` and `P-R` need to be locked.
- If `“≤ $50k”` or `“≤ $100k”` are selected in column `C` in addition to `“Single Source”`, then column `F` would be locked.
- The drop down list in column `C` may change to an estimated price that is manually entered because the current ranges are subject to change.
- If `“Bid”` is selected in column `B` and if `“≤ $50k”` or `“≤ $100k”` are selected in column `C`, the columns `P-R` & `AC` need to be locked
- Both `L5` & `A5` approvals will be locked if column `C` is under `$2M`
- Both `L4` & `A4` approvals will be locked if column `C` is under `$1M`
- Both `L3` & `A3` approvals will be locked if column `C` is under `$500k`
- Both `L2` & `A2` approvals will be locked if column `C` is under `$50k`
- `L2` & `A2` approvals will never be locked.

Any codes I have found online thus far have not worked due to my inability to successfully edit them to meet my needs so any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9memoq1hcab2a4e/Document%20Control_Test.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Many employers block DropBox.  You need to post relevant code in your question.

Comment: Please don't use Excel in this way, use a `UserForm` instead of a sheet ;).

Comment: I can try and post a screen shot but I'm not sure what you mean by relevant code.

I do not know what a UserForm is. I asked my boss what he wanted me to create this in and he specifically said Excel.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, a UserForm is a form that VBA can open that works sort of like a lite version of an application. An example of something that is a UserForm (under the covers) is any error prompt that Excel has ever shown you. You can create your own in Excel from the Visual Studio for Applications window.

Before getting to how to do what you're wanting, you mention that you want Column C to be a drop-down that allows user entered values. Excel worksheets do not allow this. It's either a drop down or a user entered value, it can't be both. Given that the list of options might not be sufficient in some cases, you should just make it a user entered cell (i.e. no drop down choices) and then validate the values entered in your macro.

You can use straight macros to do what you are wanting, and given your comment about the variability of what the VBA code should be doing, I'm going to be the heretic and say that's probably the more maintainable approach.

To make this work you'll need to edit the worksheet code to add an event handler, specifically `Worksheet_Change`

From there you should check that the cell that changed was a cell that should cause the macro to run. Based on the details in your question, you'll want to look for cells in Columns B & C, like so

```
IF LEFT(Target.Address, 3) = "$B$" OR LEFT(Target.Address, 3) = "$C$" THEN
```

At that point it probably makes sense to just call a different function that actually does the heavy lifting and pass it the row number. Example:

```
FormatMgmt(RIGHT(Target.Address, LEN(TARGET.Address) - 3), ActiveSheet.Name)
```

Then to give you an example to work off that should give you an idea of how to do all the things you listed

```
Sub FormatMgmt(rn as long, WSName as String)
    '
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    Dim CC As Range
    Set CC = ws.Range("C" & rn) 'I'm using a variable to refer to column C since we'll
        'need to use this cell quite a bit

    Application.ScreenUpdating 'Prevent Excel from updating what's displayed on your
        'computer monitor. This lets the macro run faster

    'Determine what's in Column B for the identified row
    Select Case LCase(ws.Range("B" & rn).Value) 'LCase forces all text to lower case, so
        'that capitalization doesn't mess up the comparison
        Case "single source"
            'Protect Columns E-H & P-R
            ws.Unprotect ("<whatever_your_password_is>") 'The password is optional, but
                'you need to unlock the sheet to change whether cells are protected

            ws.Range("E" & rn & ":H" & rn).Locked = True

            'Check if column F needs locked. Note, you said if <=50k OR <=100k selected
            'should do this. Since I'm assuming a user entered value, I have to take the
            'tigher constraint
            If CC.Value <= 50000 Then
                'Lock column F.
                ws.Range("F" & rn).Locked = True
            End If

            'Check if L3, L4, L5, A3, A4, or A5 need locked. Note: you're last bullet
            'says A2 & L2 should never be locked, which contradicts the bullet
            'immediately prior. I assumed the later bullet took precedence. Also, I
            'assumed the conditions in the last 5 bullets stacked (i.e. CC < $500k means
            'A3-A5 & L3-5 should be locked)
            If CC.Value < 2000000 Then
                ws.Range("L5").Locked = True
                ws.Range("A5").Locked = True
            End If

            If CC.Value < 1000000 Then
            '...
            'Fill in the rest of the code here. You should have enough to start
            '...
            'NOTE: Be sure to put in appropriate logic to UNDO any of the cell locking
            'if a cell's value changes as well

        'Relock the sheet
        WS.Protect"<whatever_your_password_is>")

        'At the very end of the macro be sure to turn screen updating back on (no
        'good doing all this if it doesn't show on the screen)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

That should be plenty to get you started. If not, do a Google search for a more specific problem and you should come up with an answer pretty quick (that's how I learned VBA, VB.net, C#, SQL, etc.)